# Is there a way to have a generated column showing the id of a related table

Tags: database, db2

I am working on an application backed by a DB2 database

In this database, I got three tables, that we will call A, B and C. 
A has a a relation to B, and B a relation to C.

[image: diagram]

> What I would want to have is a third column in A, named C_ID, which
>   would have the value of the column Id of the joined table C and to
>   have this column immutable and automatically computed. A little like a
>   view but limited to a column.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: There's a couple of different options: 1) Have a trigger that fires that updates a new column in `A`, or 2), use a view/MQT `A'` that has the extra column.  _Why_ do you want to do this, though?  This is a deliberate denormalization, which is best to avoid in "pure" design.

Comment: Because our technical architect want to have this data (C_ID) in A, to allow facilitation of future possible migration case (I will not go further in details, as it is very bound to the business). 
Having something like a virtual column (like a view, but for a column only) would allow to give him what he want, and in the same time reduce risk of data inconsistency (A.C_ID different of B.C_ID)

Comment: ... yeah, I'm still suspicious.  You're saying that in the future you may remove `C_ID` from `B`?  For one thing, such a migration would imply that the actual data relationship changed.  It would mean that `C` is no longer related to `B`, except tangentially (via `A`).  Such changes usually require massive updates elsewhere (ie, DAOs modified to move the respective class, changes in the order of updates).  YAGNI probably applies.  Otherwise... I'd likely start with a view that just joins `A` and `B`, and go from there if performance is a problem.

Comment: The migration is more complex that removing C_ID (As I said, it is a business problem) but I totally agree with you about the usefullness of this solution. But it is a way to avoid the *first* requirement of our achitect, which would be to have the A.C_ID managed by the application side...
ie. each time we create or modify an instance of A in the application, we need to be sure that A.C_ID is the same value than B.C_ID... and that if B.C_ID value change, we need to report this change in the application...

Comment: Having dealt with application-managed ids (although thankfully they were never updated), you don't want to do that.  I'm also concerned because the way the question is written implies that these are brand-new tables, which would beg the question "why design this way _now_ ?".  I'd still start off with a view and go from there, especially as enforcing immutability is problematic.

Comment: Your question really needs to explain *why* you want to do this.  Going into the details is exactly what will help you get a good answer.

Comment: Ok. For the record, I don't want to implement this feature (having A.C_ID keeping the same value of B.C_ID), whatever the way, as I see it as useless and harmful. But the point is that I have no power of decision in this case. What I can do is find a way to implement this feature with minimal impact.